# Don't stick objects in Cell Item of UITableView - IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom `cell Item` in `UITableView` like bellow:

[image]

But when I run it on device show me:

[image]

I am using from `stackView(Horizontal)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `semanticContentAttribute` of the stack view.  This is a property of the UIView.  It controls how context should be handled in right-to-left languages.